# sending apache kafka logs to ELK using fluent bit

Tags: apache-kafka, fluent, elk

I have an apache kafka cluster (version 2.8). I need to send kafka logs to elasticsearch using fluent bit. The logs are sent and get into elasticsearch, but the problem is that the log is not separated by fields, the whole message is written in one log field, although I configured regexp for kafka logs. What is wrong in my configuration?

Below is fluent-bit.conf config for apache kafka

```
[INPUT]
    Name            tail
    Path            /home/kafka/kafka/logs/server.log
    Parser          apache-kafka
    Tag             apache.kafka
    Refresh_Interval 5
    Mem_Buf_Limit   5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines On

[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           apache.kafka
    Host            192.168.0.15
    Port            9200
    Index           apache-kafka-%Y.%m.%d
```

Below is parcesrs.conf config for apache kafka

```
[PARSER]
   Name    apache-kafka
   Format  regex
   Regex   ^\[(?<timestamp>[^\]]+)\] (?<log_level>\S+) \[(?<thread_name>[^\]]+)\] (?<log_message>.*)$
   Time_Key     timestamp
   Time_Format  %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L
```

Below is a piece of the apache kafka server.log log

```
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,787] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,900] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Starting socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,903] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,951] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Started data-plane acceptor and processor(s) for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,951] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Started socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,954] INFO Kafka version: 2.8.2 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,954] INFO Kafka commitId: 3146c6ff4a24cc24 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,954] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1686741245951 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2023-06-14 14:14:05,954] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-06-14 14:14:06,003] INFO [broker-0-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker fluentbit-cl1:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

Comment: How do we know the regex is correct without seeing your data?